# Wagtail large list within stream field block

Tags: python, django, wagtail

We use wagtail for our blogs that are part of an eCommerce site. When we want to add a product to the blog as it stands we have to put the exact product name in which then matches on save. As names can change this then breaks that blog which isnt ideal.

What we would like to do is add a field to our streamfield block that lets you pick from our list of products, however as we have 200k+ products and there might be up to 20 products on each blog loading the list into a dropdown is no good. What we need is to replicate what we do in Django admin using django-autocomplete-light where you start typing and get results based on that rather than loading the list into the HTML.

What we cant work out is how to do that within a streamfield block, I have seen libraries like "Wagtail Autocomplete" however it seems you can only use that as a panel rather than within a block. As far as we can see you can only use sub-classes of wagtail.core.blocks or they dont show up in the interface.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the editor. Although the examples are mainly focussed on adding CSS style, it still should be possible. You can read more on this at the documentation: http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.8/advanced_topics/customisation/extending_draftail.html#

Another option would be is to use the Wagtail autocomplete panel for specifying the product you need to reference to, in a seperate field of course. Then, using a regular f-string replacement, place the proper product details in the text.